# Multi threaded multiple sqlite commands android error

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

I am using android **SQLiteOpenHelper** to handle my sqlite database.

I am trying to do a huge amount of database commands in the background using a simple asynctask so the user wont notice the delay it would give on the main thread.
when there are multiple (a large amount) commands i always get the database cant open error.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14) os_unix.c:31278: (24) open(/data/user/0/com.locomain.app/databases/app.db-journal)
```

this does not happen when i call the command a small amount of times.

i already checked the other threads concerning this issue and also did some google searches but i couldnt find the anwser.

my code:

```
public void addTag(Tag tag){
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    db.beginTransaction();

    values.put(TagColumn.TAG_NAME,tag.getName());

    db.insert(TagColumn.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Something else already has the file open.  Do you have 2 instances of the helper class?  Its generally considered best to make that class a singleton, to prevent this problem.

Comment: no, its a singleton

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that load of queries sended to the db (source:https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#cantopen).
i fixed it by refactoring the way i handled the queries.

Answer (score -1):

Make your methods which use db `synchronized`.

Try to use threads instead of AsyncTasks, its better practic anyway.

Are you sure about using transactions? It really slows down your inserts.

Comment: i made the SQLiteOpenHelper itself synchronized. but the android guidelines state that one should use asynctask over threads right? what would be a faster way of doing this raw query?

Comment: The problem with this is that the AsyncTask has an implicit reference to the enclosing Activity. If a configuration change happens the Activity instance that started the AsyncTask would be destroyed, but not GCd until the AsyncTask finishes. Thread will not make it faster. And I dont see any advantage to use AsyncTask instead of thread, they are similar, but thread is more stable.